# Variable not Carrying Over to URL of PHP Page?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I've got a simple form that I created that, when hitting submit, will go to a PHP page that I have created called eventcreator.php; I am trying to get the $u variable (the username in this case) to carry over to the eventcreator.php page, meaning if I were to echo it on that page, it would output the $u variable.

```
<div id="pageMiddle">

<form name="eventcreator" action="eventcreator.php?u=<?php echo $u ?>" method="post">

<div>Event Name: </div>
<input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname" size="50" maxlength="75" />

<div>Month:</div>
<select name="eventdatemonth" id="eventdatemonth" >
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button3" value="Create My Event!" onsubmit="checkForm();" />
```

It seems to work fine for my other site pages when I use a href, for example, if I use the following:

```
<p>Click <a href="calendar.php?u=<?php echo $u ?>">here</a> to create an event!</p>
```

it will successfully bring me to www.mysitename.com/calendar.php$u=sampleusername, but for some reason, even when I submit the form above, it only brings me to eventcreator.php; can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Your JavaScript function of checkForm() may have an error which is preventing the correct action to be performed.

Comment: Post your javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<div id="pageMiddle">

<form name="eventcreator" action="eventcreator.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="u" value="<?php echo $u; ?>"/>

<div>Event Name: </div>
<input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname" size="50" maxlength="75" />

<div>Month:</div>
<select name="eventdatemonth" id="eventdatemonth" >
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button3" value="Create My Event!" onsubmit="checkForm();" />
```

Here, make a `hidden field` in the form . so that on submit the form it will send it to you `eventcreator.php` and then you get your `u` variable by using `$_POST`.

**eventcreator.php :**

```
$username = $_POST['u'];

echo $username;
```

Comment: Thank you. This technique accomplished what I was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: @aoigengo: Make sure you encode on output to prevent an XSS security hole. This example code does not prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

**Error 1:**

In your form you have mentioned method as `POST` but the url you are trying to construct seems to be `GET` method.

**Error 2:**

```
onsubmit attribute is for forms not for input elements

<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
</form>
```

And show us your java script to analyze more

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Using the hidden field line as suggested above accomplished the task for me.